# Permalink structure with custom taxonomies and custom post type like /parent-tax/child-tax/custom-post-type-name (with no base name)

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have a custom post type named "tours" and a custom taxonomy named "tour_type".

"tour-type" taxonomy is hierarchical. In "tour-type" taxonomy, parent terms are limited to "eco-tours", "daily-tours", "package-tours" & "tailor-made-tours". All terms except "tailor-made-tours", have children.

I'm trying to reach a permalink structure like below for my tour post type:

> /parent-tax/child-tax(if exist)/custom-post-type-name

For example it would end up like this:

> mysite.com/eco-tours/diving-and-rafting/coast-to-coast/
>
> Or like this (for "tailor-made-tours"):
>
> mysite.com/tailor-made-tours/margoon-waterfall/

I read lots of tutorials and solutions which lead me to these parts of code:

```
$tours_args = array(
    'labels'                => $tours_labels, //Some Labels
    'public'                => true,
    'menu_position'         => 10,
    'query_var'             => true,
    'rewrite'               => array('slug'=>'%tour_type%'),
    'supports'              => $custom_post_types_supports,
    'hierarchical'          => true,
);
register_post_type('tours',$tours_args);


add_filter('post_type_link', 'filter_post_type_link', 10, 2);
function filter_post_type_link($link, $post)
{
    if ($post->post_type == 'tours')
    {
        /*...
        Some codes which make $term equal to "parent-tax/child-tax"
        ...*/

        $link = str_replace('%tour_type%', $term, $link);
    }
    return $link;
}


add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'mmp_rewrite_rules');
function mmp_rewrite_rules($rules) {
    $newRules  = array();

    $newRules['eco-tours/(.+)/(.+)/?$']         = 'index.php?post_type=tours&tour_types=eco-tours&custom_post_type_name=$matches[2]';
    $newRules['daily-tours/(.+)/(.+)/?$']       = 'index.php?post_type=tours&tour_types=daily-tours&custom_post_type_name=$matches[2]';
    $newRules['package-tours/(.+)/(.+)/?$']     = 'index.php?post_type=tours&tour_types=package-tours&custom_post_type_name=$matches[2]';
    $newRules['tailor-made-tours/(.+)/?$']      = 'index.php?post_type=tours&tour_types=tailor-made-tours&custom_post_type_name=$matches[1]';

    return array_merge($newRules, $rules);
}
```

Now, permalinks which are shown in post type edit pages, are showing the right url, but when I open each of them, they show an archive page of "tour" post type...

What did I drop in my codes?! :(

Comment: do you have a single-tour.php template? See more here : http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: @Laxmana , I just made one, but it didn't work... The problem is that wordpress behave these urls as taxonomy archive page, not a single post page.

Comment: Please try to save your permalinks structure(Settings -> Permalinks) and try again.

Comment: oh I just saw that your custom post name is being called tours and no tour. So the file should be single-tours.php. It's single-mycustompostname.php

Comment: @Laxmana Still not working... :(

Comment: Xmm. Ok so if you type mysite.com/tours/custom-post-type-name the single-tours.php is being generated ? I am asking to isolate the problem even more.

Comment: It would get redirect to:
mysite.com/parent-tax/child-tax/custom-post-type-name